# How to reduce asp net core hosted blazor web assembly initial load time?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-7.0

I have developed a website using ASP.NET Core 7 hosted Blazor web assembly. I have implemented a custom authentication state provider for the client web assembly project. I have many other projects like (servers, shared, infrastructure, data, etc.)

The problem is when it starts, it takes too long to show something on the screen.

Here is my client's `program.cs` file:

```
var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
builder.Services.AddBlazoredSessionStorage();

builder.Services.AddBlazoredToast();
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, CustomAuthStateProvider>();

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

Is there any way to make the initial load faster?

I tried pre-rending but could not do that without breaking the architecture.

N.B: I have a lot of pages, so I guess is there any mechanism to lazy load the routes? Could not find anything effective.

Answer (score 0):

> How to reduce asp net core hosted blazor web assembly initial load
> time?

Actually, based on your scenario and descriptions apparently the most effective way to increase faster loading time by implementing [Prerendering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/prerendering-and-integration?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=webassembly) and [Lazy load assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/webassembly-lazy-load-assemblies?view=aspnetcore-7.0) which already you have tried and as per your statements it seems doesn't work accordingly.

Althogh Prerendering and Lazy load assemblies are not the only way to improve performance but still not sure what exactly you tried and what didn't helped.

Cast aside all these, you could also consider following mechanism in order to improve performance. In other words, following aspects also might impact on application efficiency:

**1.** While loading your components make sure there is no unnecessary component sub-trees which significantly impact loading time. Thus, Avoid unnecessary rendering.

**2.** Consider virtualization while displaying large amount of UI elements.

**3.** Make sure, your components are lightweight and fully optimized. Double check them if they are not large in chunk or if can can be reusable. Always consider making components resuable which eventually make the whole app lightweight.

**4.** Verbosely object instance creation also cause over memory consumption which critically impact on loading time. Therefore, possibly avoid creating unnecessary object within your application code.

**5.** Overly uses of external link or uncessary script link references also cause slowness. In addition to this, event triggers and some features which not being used should be removed.

Most importantly, as we may know there are not direct option or way to improve application performnce dramatically. However, above steps would definitely imply significant positive impact.

**Note:** On top on this, I would higly recommend you to [check this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/performance?view=aspnetcore-7.0) in order to check if your application has followed by those practices.